How will hitting the gym trigger the effect of the drug?
Before taking the Lemmon 714 drug, Jordan Belfort had gotten rid of anything in his
body that might interfere with the high. Despite this, and despite taking more than
enough of the drug to get high, it still wasn’t showing any effects on him or Donnie.
So, they hit the gym:

How will hitting the gym trigger the effect of the drug?

Physical efforts boost/affect drugs effects, as explained by The Effects of Exercise on the Pharmacokinetics of Drugs. By cleaning the body first, they open the door to the new drug(s) :

Exercise may influence the rate and extent of absorption, distribution, metabolism, and excretion of drugs by changing some of the physiological factors. The effect of exercise on the absorption of drugs depends on the route of administration. In addition, its effect on drug distribution mainly depends on the extent of drug distribution. However, other factors also may be involved in the drug distribution during exercise which make the relationship more complicated. Exercise may decrease clearance of highly extracted drugs which may consequently lead to increased plasma concentrations. On the other hand, exercise may increase total body clearance of some other drugs (e.g., the anionic drug acetaminophen) by increasing their biliary excretion leading to decreased plasma concentrations. The plasma concentrations of drugs primarily eliminated by the kidneys increase due to decreased renal excretion during exercise.


Whilst awesome info, this is more "the actual real-world situation"; the "in universe situation" is given in the excellent answer via @Valorum.

@Fattie: and does it make it less useful?

Pad - I wasn't criticizing, just observing!

@Fattie don't they match, given it's a realistic movie? I mean, it's most likely the characters use the same reasoning

@clabacchio: agreed, as between an 'in-universe' and 'reality' possible explanation, I'll almost every time pick the latter, because, in-universe, unicorns can fly even though in reality it's much more difficult :D

@clabacchio oh, I don't know, not really. The characters were using a "silly, humorous" take on the drug issue, as in any comedy film about drugs. Or just like two guys in real life. (As it states clearly in the answer quoting the book, they "... were under the impression that ...")  The actual full scientific picture is more complex (as it says in the quoted science article, exercise can have the OTHER effect). It's like if you and I were goofing about how marijuana makes you hungry - that's a funny cliché but it's not really fully scientific, it's a "funny cliché".  Anyway.

Note too that Our Local Hallucinogenics Expert Dave™ below has given a fuller explanation.

According to the real Jordan Belfort, he and Danny (AKA 'Donnie') were labouring under the impression that exercise causes quaaludes to kick in faster. Something to do with the metabolism, apparently.

Chemical-tob said, “They’re the real deal, Jordan. Whatever you do,
don’t take more than one. They’re not like the Palladins; they’re much
stronger.”
I assured him I wouldn’t…and, ten minutes later, Danny and I were well
on the road to paradise. Each of us had swallowed one Real Real, and
we were now in my basement gym, surrounded by floor-to-ceiling
mirrors. The gym was packed with state-of-tha-art Cybex equipment and
enough dumbbells and barbells and benches and squat racks to impress
Arnold Schwarzenegger. Danny was walking on a motorized treadmill at a
brisk pace; I was on the StairMaster, climbing, as if Agent Coleman
were chasing me.
I said to Danny, “Nothing kicks in a Quaalude better than exercise,
right?”
“Absa-fuckin-lutely!” exclaimed Danny. “It’s all in the metabolism;
the faster, the better.” He reached over and picked up a white
porcelain sake cup. “And this is genius, by the way. Drinking hot sake
after consuming a real Lemmon is inspirational. Like pouring gasoline
on a raging fire.”
I grabbed my own sake cup and reached over to clink cups with Danny.
Danny tried too, but the two pieces of equipment were six feet apart,
and we found ourselves just out of reach.
The Wolf of Wall Street by Jordan Belfort


This is indeed the actual "in universe situation" explained and answered. (Info on the "the real-world facts" about the chemicals can be seen in the @Padawan answer.)

One of the idiosyncrasies of Lemmon 714 was not apparent to these two. Jordan on the stationary bike, Danny on the treadmill were getting opposite affects. 'L 714'-its original purpose was to adjust the spatial distortion the mind introduced to counteract actual movement so our astronauts could actually manage the long days of space. the affect Jordan was feeling was that he was constantly increasing his speed although he was running at 3 miles and hour, with Danny on the bike, experiencing himself moving backwards at an ever increasing rate.
These two were going to be real sore after this, with Danny running full speed into the wall after he dismounted the treadmill and Jordan backpedaling into the mirror!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Fantastic expert answer.  @DaveC you are now Note too that Our Local Hallucinogenics Expert Dave™   :O
